# Node red throwinr error suddenly

Tags: node-red

Unable to understand what is wrong. Worked till yesterday.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

Output of netstat -ntlo | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40171         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3417/GoogleTalkPlug
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5965/mosquitto  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42846         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3417/GoogleTalkPlug
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN      5965/mosquitto
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have a node somewhere trying to access port 8080, but there's nothing listening in that port. Without details of your flow it is impossible to say anything else.

Comment: Are the flows in $HOME/.node-red/flows_<hostname>.conf ?

Comment: Hey, I have removed that flow where 8080 was present, it seems to work now. Thank you. But why it has to refuse 8080?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Node-RED doesn't use 8080 anywhere unless you've configured it to do so - it uses 1880 by default. As I said, without knowing the details of your flow that was trying to access 8080, I can't tell you why it wasn't working.